# Obj-C, Puzzled by this xcode warning, warning: 'BNColor' may not respond to '+beInit'?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

I've getting this warning `warning: 'BNColor' may not respond to '+beInit'` I'm not sure why.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: are you importing NSObject+Be.h into BNColor.h?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included/imported `NSObject+Be.h` in `BNColor.m`?

Also, methods whose names contain `init` and `copy` should return objects owned by the caller, i.e., don’t autorelease them.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are using a third party library that exposes an BNColor class and you are trying to send the class object, BNColor, the beInit class method, which the BNColor class apparently doesn't respond to (that is, beInit is not defined as a class method of BNColor).

Comment: Both are from the same author, I think it may be due to the newer compiler, any ideas on a fix ?